# How to use time.h to convert from an older year to now in terms of seconds(I started getting a negative number)

Tags: c

Yes, this is long ways, but I'm trying to do it in a basic way.
The compiler started to display all the numbers as negative, when at first they were positive, and I can't figure out why.
I know this looks complex, I do not know how to do it yet, as I am not working with structs yet or anything more than the basic format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {



    // now = time(NULL);  <----????? (now is more than a billion seconds - this would be long double, right?
    // long double now; 
    int CurrentYear = 2017;
    int CurrentMonth = 2;
    int CurrentDay = 10;

    int OldYear = 1970;
    int OldMonth = 1;
    int OldDay = 1;

    int YearsPassed; // 47 years passed
    int MonthsPassed; // 1 month passed
    int DaysPassed;  // 9 days passed

    int YearsPassedInDays;
    // 1533338720 days passed

    int DaysToHours;
    int Hours = 24;
    int Minutes = 60;

    int HoursToMinutes;
    int MinutesToSeconds;
    int Seconds = 60;


    YearsPassedInDays = YearsPassed * 365;
    printf("YearsPassedInDays = %d\n", YearsPassedInDays);
     // 1533338720 days passed

     DaysToHours = YearsPassedInDays * Hours;
     printf("DaysToHours = %d\n", DaysToHours);
     // DaysToHours: 610015968 hours

     HoursToMinutes = DaysToHours * Minutes;
     printf("HoursToMinutes = %d\n", HoursToMinutes);
     // HoursToMinutes: 392762944 minutes

     // MinutesToSeconds = HoursToMinutes * Seconds;
     // printf("MinutesToSeconds = %d\n", MinutesToSeconds);
```

Comment: You ought to have read the `time()` documentation before second guessing. It returns a `time_t`, so your `now` variable must be declared as `type_t now;`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use function difftime from time.h library

```
double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time2)
```

> Returns the difference of seconds between time1 and time2 (time1-time2). [1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm)